# Differences rendering a gradient using a FBO in GLES2 and GLES3

Tags: android, linux, opengl-es, jogl, fbo

I'm using JOGL as part of a cross platform app. I'm requesting a GLES2 GL profile to be used.

I've got a FBO bound and content drawn into it, before unbinding it & drawing the backing texture to the screen - pretty standard draw-to-texture stuff.

I've got 3 different types of drawing I've tested so far, block colour shader, gradient shader, and a texture shader. All of these are working thus far when drawn into the default frame buffer across all devices.

Hardware involved in tests:

Linux laptop:
Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile. 
Version: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3. 
GL Profile: GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw].

Android Samsung Galaxy S3:
Renderer: Mali-400 MP. 
Version: OpenGL ES 2.0. 
GL Profile: GLProfile[GLES2/GLES2.hw].

Android Samsung Tab 4:
Renderer: Mali-T628. 
Version: OpenGL ES 3.0. 
GL Profile: GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw].

When testing rendering to texture using the FBO, I'm getting some very odd behaviour with the gradient shader only, and only on the Galaxy tab 4. What happens is I don't get any visual result back from drawing the content of the FBO, not even the clear colour I used to clear the FBO before drawing the gradient into it - and as I said the gradient does work under all other circumstances.

Furthermore, the Galaxy tab 4 gives the same correct consistant results if I draw a block colour shader or texture into the FBO & then draw the FBO content to the default frame buffer.

So the big question is - why doesn't the gradient draw into the FBO work on the tab 4? My only hunch is it's something to do with the GLES3 implementation on the Tab 4 regarding frame buffers, but I'm at a loss of where to go from here.

Whereas the Galaxy S3 uses GLES2 and a normal GL_FRAMEBUFFER component, the Tab 4 is running GLES3 and uses a GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER and a GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER - but remember it's fine drawing a block colour or texture into the FBO, only the gradient doesn't show up. Like I said, odd..

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Unless somebody has seen exactly the same thing, I doubt that they will be able to help you. If you're convinced that your code is correct, you may want to file a bug with the vendor. Have you tried calling `glValidateProgram()` after you set up all the state, and before you start drawing? Does it give a positive validation status?

Comment: I tried glValidateProgram, everything comes back Ok but it was nice to discover that function and put it to use so thank you for that :) It does indeed seem to be something unique to this model of device. To be more precise - from further testing - an ordinary Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 works fine, it's just the larger scale version of it, the Note? that has this issue.

Comment: are you catching any gl error?

Comment: Non that I can see - I've tried running with full logging and followed every OpenGL command being made between the devices that work and the device that doesn't. And glValidateProgram checks return that everything is ok. As for catching errors, I'm not aware of any catches of my own, unless the JOGL library is doing any - in which case I'm not sure how to find out other than going through the code.. it may come that :/